# Send file using retrofit that follows specific request body

Tags: android, postman, retrofit2

Is it even possible to send files as shown in the postman screenshot below ? I know that we can send the files as if it became top level objects. Something like below:

```
@Multipart
@POST("audition/register-member")
Observable<ResponseObject<String>> sendAuditionData(@Part("name") RequestBody name,
                                                   @Part("contact") RequestBody contact,
                                                   @NotNull @Part("district") RequestBody district,
                                                   @Part("estdDate") RequestBody estdDate,
                                                   @Part("reason") RequestBody reason,
                                                   @Part("type") RequestBody type,
                                                   @Part("link") RequestBody link,
                                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part video,
                                                   @Part MultipartBody.Part image
                                                  );
// eg: of creating body
val name = RequestBody.create("multipart/form-data".toMediaType(), fullName)
val imageBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", selectedFile?.getName(), fileBody); // fileBody is (ProgressRequestBody impl RequestBody)
```

But how do we send the members array object with file as shown in postman below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all please make one data class for this Json like this...

```
data class ReqAuditionData(

@field:SerializedName("members")
val members: ArrayList<Members>? = ArrayList(),

@field:SerializedName("name")
val name: String = "",

 @field:SerializedName("district")
val district: String = "",

//same for other fields
)
```

then directly put this data class as parameter to Interface method...

```
@Multipart
@POST("audition/register-member")
Observable<ResponseObject<String>> sendAuditionData(@Body reqAuditionData : ReqAuditionData);
```

Comment: But how do you attach file to that data class.Will it work, if we just declare the field as File type. Also, does multipart accept @Body annotations ? I had used that previously if all the field are text. I don't know if that works ??  I need to give it a shot. Anyway thanks.https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/1785#issuecomment-275987226

Answer (score 1):

This is how I implemented sending image to the server using post method

api file:

```
@POST("api/profilepic/")
@Multipart
Call<PostResult> updateProfile(@Header("Authorization") String token,
                                       @Part MultipartBody.Part file,
                                       @Part("value") RequestBody name);
```

Calling Api:

```
File file = new File(files[0]);
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);
MultipartBody.Part fileUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), requestBody);
RequestBody filename = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), file.getName());
retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(SERVER_NAME)
                        .client(UnsafeOkHttpClient.getUnsafeOkHttpClient())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .build();
                api = retrofit.create(GetRemindersApi.class);
                Call<PostResult> call1 = api.updateProfile("Token " + token, fileUpload, filename);
                call1.enqueue(new Callback<PostResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<PostResult> call, @NonNull Response<PostResult> response) {
                        PostResult result = response.body();
                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(result).getResult().equals("success")) {
                            profileImage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ProfileView.this, result.getError(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<PostResult> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileView.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

and it works fine for me.